# Application bar not available

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I have recently downloaded `Windows Phone Toolkit` (`November 2011, 7.1 SDK`) but I do not see a few icons in my `Visual Studio toolbox` like `Application bar`, am I missing some other installations?

Comment: Seriously. Don't use the Toolbox. Get Expression Blend, if you want a visual designer (which, by the way, also supports your missing controls in a toolbox like fashion.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controls (like Panorama, Pivot, AppBar) aren't in the Toolbox, because they're not widgets like buttons, text boxes, etc - the compiler treats them differently, and they're not designed to be 'placed' anywhere or used multiple times on a page like widgets are.

Here's the XAML for the panorama, pivot and app bar, copied from the default projects, for reference;

Panorama

```
<controls:Panorama Title="my panorama">
            <controls:Panorama.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="PanoramaBackground.png"/>
            </controls:Panorama.Background>
            <controls:PanoramaItem Header="nearby" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="880">
<!--stuff goes here-->
            </controls:PanoramaItem>
</controls:Panorama>
```

Pivot

```
<controls:Pivot Title="my pivot">
        <controls:PivotItem Header="item 1">
            <!-- stuff goes here -->
        </controls:PivotItem>
</controls:Pivot>
```

App bar

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="Button 1"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" Text="Button 2"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 1"/>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 2"/>
            </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

Comment: To be fair, his biggest problem is likely that he needs to add a reference to the `Microsoft.Phone.Controls` assembly, before the Pivot and Panorama controls are available. (The `shell`, however, is always available).

Also, I think you should post the xmlns decelerations. If he already knew them, he wouldn't have asked ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Application Bar sample is added into the bottom of every new page that is created by VS Express for Windows Phone.

```
 <!--Sample code showing usage of ApplicationBar-->
<!--   <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="btnCancel" IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="OK"/>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

You have to uncomment it and modify to suit your needs.